# Recordset.FindFirst method: why DOES it work with some of my Table-type recordsets?

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao, recordset

I was trying to use the `Recordset.FindFirst` method with DAO recordsets, in Access VBA, when I came across the error:

> Error 3251: "Operation is not supported for this type of object."

After some brief investigation on the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194787.aspx), I discovered that the method only works on `dynaset-type` or `snapshot-type` recordsets. I changed my code from this:

```
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("table_name")
rs2.FindFirst [search criteria]
```

to this:

```
Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset("table_name", dbOpenDynaset)
rs2.FindFirst [search criteria]
```

and all was working fine.

---

However, I have another database where I have been using `FindFirst` on `table-type` recordsets without error.

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblUsers")
rs.FindFirst [search criteria]
```

My questions are

1. Why this works in one database and not another, and
2. If it would be advisable to change the code to use `dbOpenDynaset` type recordsets instead?

Comment: How are you declaring rs and rs2? ADODB?

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer. DAO.

Comment: Mark, take a look at this. Has some good info. http://allenbrowne.com/ser-29.html

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. The key line is "When you OpenRecordset() on a query or attached table, Access defaults to a Dynaset type (dbOpenDynaset). When you OpenRecordset() on a local table, it defaults to a Table type (dbOpenTable.)". My table for `rs` in linked, whereas my table for `rs2` is local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you OpenRecordset() on a query or attached table, Access defaults to a Dynaset type (dbOpenDynaset).

When you OpenRecordset() on a local table, it defaults to a Table type (dbOpenTable.)